# Extracting a section of text from text file using python

Tags: python, regex, pyparsing

Considering the following text file:

```
%zap1 inside1 guhn1
%triso huin lkjkljlk
%njkjkjkj{mnlkjkl lkj={kl} lkjlkj %as
kjnkjn knkjnh kjnkjnkj={kl} knkjnkj %as
uyiu kojo={kl} lkjlk lkjlkj lkjlkj}

%zap2 inside2 guhn2
%triso huin lkjkljlk
%njkjkjkj{mnlkjkl lkj={kl} lkjlkj %as
kjnkjn knkjnh kjnkjnkj={kl} knkjnkj %as
uyiu kojo={kl} lkjlk lkjlkj lkjlkj}

%zap3 inside3 guhn3
%triso huin lkjkljlk
%njkjkjkj{mnlkjkl lkj={kl} lkjlkj %as
kjnkjn knkjnh kjnkjnkj={kl} knkjnkj %as
uyiu kojo={kl} lkjlk lkjlkj lkjlkj}
```

How can one extract for example the following section (para 3) from the above text file? I prefer to use regular expression or may be pyparsing if possible.

```
%zap3 inside3 guhn3
%triso huin lkjkljlk
%njkjkjkj{mnlkjkl lkj={kl} lkjlkj %as
kjnkjn knkjnh kjnkjnkj={kl} knkjnkj %as
uyiu kojo={kl} lkjlk lkjlkj lkjlkj}
```

Is there any solution available in python which will let me process the extracted text (like a list may be)?

Comment: You mean the last paragraph?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Not exactly the last para. It could be any para but it starts with `%zap3 inside3 guhn3` and ends with `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to get the last paragraph.

```
with open(file) as f:
    for i in re.split(r'\n\n+', f.read()):
        if i.startswith('%zap3 inside3 guhn3'):
            print i
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regex to get list of paragraphs.

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as input:
    my_list = []
    para = ''
    for line in input:
        if line != '\n':
            para += line
        else:
            my_list.append(para)
            para = ''
    my_list.append(para)

for item in my_list:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use regex and can be sure that the paragraphs are always separated by two newlines, you can use this:

```
match = re.search(r'(%zap3 .+?)(?=\n\n)', s, re.DOTALL)
```

Then, to get the text of the whole paragraph, you can use

```
match.group(0)
```

EDIT: As you mentioned you are looking for paragraphs ending with `}`, the regex would be this:

```
(\n\n|^)(%zap3 .+?})(?=\n\n)
```

This also fixes a problem with the previous one which finds `%zap3` *anywhere* within the string, not just at the beginning of the paragraph.